# Implementation of IAlertUpdateHandler

Tags: alert, email, 2007

Has anyone implemented `IAlertUpdateHandler` interface successfully?

Actually I've to suppress alert subscription notification email. I've following code in `PreUpdate` method:

```
public bool PreUpdate(SPAlert a, SPWeb web, bool newAlert, string properties)
{
    if (CHECK_IF_SUPPRESSING_EMAIL)
    {
        a.Update(false);
    }
    else
    {
        a.Update();
    }
    return true;//have tried returning false also
}
```

but I'm getting `StackOverFlow` exception as the method is called recursively. Any clues about what is going wrong?

EDIT:- I've tried using `PostUpdate` also but got same results.

Comment: Haven't really used this one yet, only aware that it exists. If you are calling a.Update() aren't you initiating a PreUpdate again?

Answer (score 1):

I know that it might be a bit late for this but I thought put it anyway to help the next one.

I found a solution/hack for this problem.

I beleive that when the alert is created from the UI the system fires an SPAlert.update(), so what I came up with is to do similar but ignore the update called from the UI to do that I added a custom property to the SPAlert property bag.

```
public bool PreUpdate(SPAlert a, SPWeb web, bool newAlert, string properties)
{
    if (CHECK_IF_SUPPRESSING_EMAIL && !a.Properties.ContainsKey("CustomUpdate"))
    {
        //add a property to identify this update
        a.Properties.Add("CustomUpdate", ""); //can be called anything :)
        a.Update(false);
        //return false to ignore the update sent by the UI
        return false;
    }
    else 
    {
       //no changes here proceed with custom behaviour
       return true;
    }

}
```

I have tested and it seems to do the trick hope this helps someone :)

Renzo

Comment: I really like this solution. The check for the custom property stops recursive calls from PreUpdate > Update > PreUpdate > Update etc. Nice one

Comment: Glad you liked it!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be using OnNotification in the IAlertNotifyHandler interface.

```
public bool OnNotification(SPAlertHandlerParams ahp)
{
    if (CHECK_IF_SUPPRESSING_EMAIL)    
    {        
        return false;    
    }    
    else    
    {        
        return true;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops, now that I re-read your question, I think you are trying to suppress the alert creation confirmation e-mail and not an alert itself.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Steve `IAlertNotifyHandler.OnNotification` is not called when alert subscription is created it is called when actual alert is sent.

Comment: Yea, that's what I figured when I re-read your question.  Thanks.